# Loading DB2 from file always missing the 1st row 1st column value

Tags: bash, csv, db2

I'm doing some Proof of concept work where I'm loading a table using the following form: `LOAD FROM ${CSVFILE} OF DEL MESSAGES ${CSVFILE}.LOADMSG REPLACE INTO T_TABLE`

For the 1st row I'm always getting `SQL3119 The value in row "F0-1" and column "1" could not be converted to an integer value, so a null value was loaded instead.`

Examining the CSV file, column data in 1st row is same as in the other rows which gets loaded without an issue. One thing that could be causing this issue is that I'm deleting the header row in csv file - but I'm not seeing anything off in data when examining the csv.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Please, upload your sample file and provide table DDL to check.

Comment: Always a user error , in my experience. How exactly are you deleting the header-line? If you preserve the header-line (and temporarily ignore the resulting error message) do you __then__ get the first data line accepted?

Comment: I was opening the file in Excel, selecting  and deleting the row, after using the sed command to delete the row issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is the BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

if it is the case you need to delete the BOM (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)